# Expo app won't start after update, how to debug?

Tags: react-native, expo

I had a working app at first. Then I ran:

```
expo update
```

So now I'm on expo SDK 47.0. I started my app using `expo start`
It seems to build but visually the app stays on the splash screen. In the terminal I get:

```
Android Bundling complete 50ms

 Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in errorHandler
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in <anonymous>
at node_modules\@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:null in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.3.51:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in global code

Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in errorHandler
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in <anonymous>
at node_modules\@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in errorHandler
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in <anonymous>
at node_modules\@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I start with the first error which is related to ViewPropTypes being deprecated, but I have no idea in which file this is used...
I checked the paths beneath this error e.g.

```
node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js
```

But no ViewPropTypes import to be found...

old package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.5",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.2.4",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "5.11.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "*",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "~5.12.8",
    "@unimodules/core": "~7.2.0",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.0.0",
    "expo": "^47.0.0",
    "expo-application": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-asset": "~8.6.2",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.1.0",
    "expo-camera": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-constants": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-device": "~5.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-image-picker-multiple": "^1.4.1",
    "expo-images-picker": "^2.3.0",
    "expo-linking": "~3.2.3",
    "expo-location": "~15.0.1",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.0.0",
    "expo-network": "~5.0.0",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.17.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.15.6",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.0.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.5.0",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-dialog": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.2.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-paper": "3.6.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "*",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.2.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "unimodules-permissions-interface": "^6.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.70.6",
    "jest-expo": "^47.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

terminal error log:

```
expo start
 
This command is being executed with the global Expo CLI. Learn more: https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421
To use the local CLI instead (recommended in SDK 46 and higher), run:
› npx expo start
 
Starting project at C:\Users\Niya\Desktop\Opdrachten\abc_app\img_upload
Starting Metro Bundler
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █▄▄▄ ▀ ▀█▄█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █
█ █   █ ██▄▀ █  ███ █   █ █
█ █▄▄▄█ ██▀▄ ▄ ██▀█ █▄▄▄█ █
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█ ▀▄█ ▀ ▀ █▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█
█  ▀  █▄▀█▄▀█▄██▀ █▄█▀█▀▀▄█
████▀▀ ▄▀▄▄██▄█   ▀███▄▀▀ █
█▀▄▄▄█▀▄▀   █▀█▄ █ ▄▀▀█▀ ██
█ ▄ █▄▀▄██▀▄█▀▄█ ▄▀ ██▄▀  █
█▄█▄▄▄█▄▄ ▀▀ ▄▄ █ ▄▄▄  ▄▀▄█
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ ██▀█▀▄  █ █▄█ ███ █
█ █   █ █ ▄ ▄ ██▄ ▄  ▄ █▀▀█
█ █▄▄▄█ █▀▀▀  █▄ ▄█▀▀▄█   █
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▄█▄██▄▄▄▄█▄▄███▄█
 
› Metro waiting on exp://192.168.3.61:19000
› Scan the QR code above with Expo Go (Android) or the Camera app (iOS)
 
› Press a │ open Android
› Press w │ open web
 
› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu
 
› Press ? │ show all commands
 
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
Started Metro Bundler
Android Bundling complete 4501ms
 
Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in errorHandler
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in <anonymous>
at node_modules\@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:null in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.3.61:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in global code
 
Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in errorHandler
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in <anonymous>
at node_modules\@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
 
Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in errorHandler
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in <anonymous>
at node_modules\@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

[image: screenshot terminal log]

I updated all my packages to the latest version using the following command:

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install
```

new package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "*",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "~6.3.10",
    "@unimodules/core": "~7.2.0",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.0.0",
    "expo": "^47.0.9",
    "expo-application": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-asset": "~8.7.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.1.0",
    "expo-camera": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-constants": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-device": "~5.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-image-picker-multiple": "^1.4.1",
    "expo-images-picker": "^2.5.1",
    "expo-linking": "~3.3.0",
    "expo-location": "~15.0.1",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.0.0",
    "expo-network": "~5.0.0",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.17.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.15.6",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.0.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.5.0",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-dialog": "^9.3.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-paper": "5.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.2",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "*",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.10",
    "react-navigation": "^4.2.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "unimodules-permissions-interface": "^6.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.7",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.26",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.70.8",
    "jest-expo": "^47.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The error remains the same.

Comment: It seems like you use old dependency on expo project. Can you share the package.json file to check?

Comment: @SamuelLee I copied my package.json to a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ZGf0UADi)

Comment: Can you share full error log screenshot? Thank you

Comment: @SamuelLee I added the screenshot and the log to my question!

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `@react-native-community/masked-view dependency`? If yes, it's old dependency. You should update it as new version. And Its name changed as `@react-native-masked-view/masked-view`

Comment: I don't think I still use this module. I removed it using `yarn remove @react-native-community/masked-view` I tried to restart my app but the error log is still the same

Comment: I can see there are many dependencies in your package.json file. So, you should upgrade all dependencies to new versions. I am sure the error came from old dependencies.

Comment: I updated all my packages to the latest version (updated my question). Still the same error...